# JButton from different class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

please help me with this issue.
How to create a JButton from a different class, is it even possible?
The first button is here the second is not:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Source {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setSize(640, 360);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jb = new JButton("first button");
        jb.setBounds(50, 50, 110, 20);

        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(new Button());
    }

}

class Button extends JButton {
    public Button(){
        JButton jb = new JButton("second button");
        jb.setBounds(0, 0, 110, 20);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

Code executing within a non static class method operate with an implicit this reference referring to the instance that you created and called those methods with (or in the case of a constructor, a reference to what you are creating), so you would do the following to fix your code, where the method calls refer to here that "new Button()" you created on the line of "jf.add(new Button());":

Change

```
    JButton jb = new JButton("second button");
    jb.setBounds(0, 0, 110, 20);
```

to

```
    setText("second button");
    setBounds(0, 0, 110, 20);
```

Comment: Dear NESPowerGlove, thank you very much, worked like a charm. Though I have a follow-up question if you don't mind. Thus we still create a new JButton Object only changing its text and bounds on-the-go, correct? So a proper way is an abstract class instead of a different class? Generally speaking how to do it properly if I need different constructors for the buttons?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your questions, but your first question, I believe you are asking if we created an instance of a JButton (more specifically an instance of a Button which is a specialized JButton) that we can no longer refer to or use again because we simply called new Button() without saving that reference to a variable, and that is correct we cannot refer to it again if we just create one without saving it off somehow. Your second question, are you asking how to properly create more JButtons? just make more buttons with new JButton(), JButton button2 = new JButton() and so on.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think I got it. Thanks for the explanations.